# is this ER diagram correct, according to the scenario?

Tags: entity-relationship, erd

“A multi-screen cinema wants to create a database for the items that
cleaners collect at the end of each film being shown, to improve the
recycling operations of the whole cinema and help the environment.
The organisation of the database is as follows. Each item that
cleaners collect will be given a record in the database. Information
stored for a given item consists of an ID number, type of rubbish it
represents (plastic, aluminium/can, glass, paper, non-recyclable
item), approximate weight, and size (small, medium, big). Items will
be collected from different screen rooms (locations). Each location
will consist of a unique identifier (screen number), the number of
seats available, size of the screen (small, medium, big) and the
cleaner assigned. To improve operation, each cleaner will be assigned
to one or more locations, but multiple staff cannot be assigned to the
same location. Information held on cleaners will include staffID and
Name.”

this is my solution for this question is that right?
[image]

Comment: You could turn it in to your teacher and see what he says.

Answer (score 0):

Very good to me. But you didn't notify the primary key of the location, which is the Screen Number, ID in your case.